# Server side javascript with WebGL?

Tags: javascript, webgl, server-side

I'm thinking about learning WebGL and the first thing that comes to mind is that JavaScript is  client-side; what approach (if any) is used to have server-side JavaScript specifically related to WebGL?

Comment: How are you planning to use WebGL (graphics library) on server side?

Comment: If you mean like server-side for multiplayer games that are done in webGL, then Node.js might be the thing that you need.

Comment: [Learning WebGL](http://learningwebgl.com/blog/?page_id=1217) is where you should start. And WebGL is solely for the means of displaying stuff, it wouldn't have much use on the server side to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I am new to WebGL as well, but I still feel that this is a very advanced question you are asking. I believe it is an advanced question because of the scope of answers that exist to do what you are asking and the current problems related to proprietary WebGL.

If you have done any research into WebGL you will immediately see the need for Server Side code due to the fact that the WEbGL API code is executed within the browser and thus freely available to any knowing individual. This is not a typical circumstance for game developers who are used to shipping their code compiled.

By making use of server side controls a developer can hide a large amount of WebGL translations, shaders, and matrices, and still maintain a level of information hiding on the client side code. However, the game will never work without an active internet connection.

Since WebGL is still relatively new, and IE does not support it, expect things to change. M$ may decide that they want to build their own web API like WebGL that ends up being an ASP.NET library. All of the required complexity that currently goes into building a solution to the problem you are facing gets condensed into a 3 button Wizard.

> With that being said I think the answer to your question lies in the fate of some future technologies. For bigger goals there will more than likely be a large amount of back and forth communication; protocols like HTTP may not cut it. WebSockets or other similar technologies may be worth looking into. If you are attempting to use Canvas for something smaller just an understanding of building dynamic JavaScript may be enough.

The problem with these answers is that OpenGL is an API itself and has a specific order of operations that is not meant to be changed. This means that this approach to building a WebGL applications is very limited. Since changing GL objects may require a whole Canvas restart, a page refresh, or a new page request. This could result in effects not desirable. For now I would say aim low, but ones thing for sure WebGL is going to change the www as we web developers know it.

Comment: WebGL is in IE11 (Windows 8.1), BTW.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are looking for, probably not this... :)

but...

If you want a server side fallback for browsers not supporting WebGL, lets say for generating fixed frames as png images of some 3D scene, then you could write your 3D veiwer in C or C++, build it for OpenGL ES when targeting your server side fallback, and use [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/wiki) to target browsers supporting WebGL.